# How to get last Insert Id while logging the query using PHP-PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, last-insert-id

Recently I have been creating a function to record every changes in the database, simply I record it to a table.

Table backup_log: backupTableName, backupLastUpdate, backupLastupload

So, every time changed, its will record the date to "backup_log". 
It's runs well, but I have problem when I need Last Insert Id, I using $orderid = `$dbh->lastInsertId('orderId');` to get "last insert Id", but its return "0".
I figure out that the problem comes when I put `querylog()` function that runs another query while the `query()` function still also run. coz its using same PDO object.
So, any suggestion for me to able to get "last insert id", while runs `querylog()` ?

This is my code:

```
//$dbh is object of PDO connection

$sql = query("INSER INTO orders ...");
$orderid = $dbh->lastInsertId('orderId'); // table "orders"

function query($sql){
    #this function is not the full version, just for example
    global $dbh;
    $query=$dbh->exec($sql);

    querylog($sql); // Log every insert, delete and update query
}   

function querylog($sql){  
    global $dbh; // PDO object
    global $now;

    //Table backup_log: backupTable, backupLastUpdate, backupLastupload

    ###### Log: for insert and update ########
    #if the query too long, cut for 200 chars and convert them to array
    $sql_clean_space=str_replace(array("  ",'`'),array(" ",''),$sql); //change double space to single space
    if(strlen($sql_clean_space) > 200){
        $sql_clean_space = substr($sql_clean_space, 0, 200); // get only 200 char
    }

    $sql_array=explode(" ", $sql_clean_space); //convert to array to get the command name, insert or update
    $now_date=$now;

    #save log
    if(strtolower($sql_array[0])=='insert' or strtolower($sql_array[0])=='delete'){
        #check whether the query is insert or update
        $sqlx = "SELECT * FROM backup_log WHERE backupTable='".$sql_array[2]."'";
        $query=$dbh->query($sqlx);  
        $check_row=$query->rowCount($query);

        if($check_row){
            $sql_log="UPDATE backup_log SET backupLastUpdate='$now' WHERE backupTable='". $sql_array[2] . "'";
        }else{
            $sql_log="INSERT INTO backup_log VALUES('".$sql_array[2]."', '$now_date','$now_date')";
        } 
    }elseif(strtolower($sql_array[0])=='update'){
        $sqlx = "SELECT * FROM backup_log WHERE backupTable='".$sql_array[1]."'";
        $query=$dbh->query($sqlx);  
        $check_row=$query->rowCount($query);

        if($check_row){ 
            $sql_log="UPDATE backup_log SET backupLastUpdate='$now' WHERE backupTable='". $sql_array[1] . "'";
            }else{
            $sql_log="INSERT INTO backup_log VALUES('".$sql_array[1]."', '$now_date','$now_date')";
        }
    }
    $query_log=$dbh->exec($sql_log);
    ####### End of log ######################
}
```

Comment: Why did not you use mysqli_insert_id ?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL He already said he was using PDO, so no.  Besides, mysql_* functions are deprecated and shouldn't be used, even if they might currently work (which mysql_insert_id wouldn't in this context)

Comment: Ah ok, I have misunderstood the context

Comment: I think, rather than using lastInsertId() after ran query(), better if I put lastInsertId in query() function, and its will return the result of lastInsertId when its runs INSERT query. Thanks guys. hahah :D.

Comment: You have described my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can assign last insert id in query functions and it can be preserved while query executions. See my code below;

```
$sql = query("INSER INTO orders ...", 'orderId'); //$sql is equal to last insert id 
$orderid = $sql

function query($sql, $specific_id_column){
    #this function is not the full version, just for example
    global $dbh;
    $query=$dbh->exec($sql);
    $last_id = $dbh->lastInsertId($specific_id_column);
    querylog($sql); // Log every insert, delete and update query
    return $last_id;
}
```